# From a table get the last 100 rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, max, between

I want to retrieve the last 100 values, I've used this query:

```
SELECT * FROM values WHERE ID BETWEEN max(ID)-100 and max(ID);
```

but I receive this message:

> ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by the ID in descending order and take only the first 100 records of the result

```
SELECT * FROM values 
order by id desc
limit 100
```

This is the more reliable version since there can be gaps in the ID sequence which would make your query  inaccurate (besides of it being wrong syntactically).

Comment: Nice it works, there is a way to obtain in inverse order?

Comment: Put another query around it: `select * from (SELECT * FROM values 
order by id desc limit 100) tmp order by id asc`

Comment: (Assuming, quite reasonably, that id is the primary key- and hence, unique)

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not very clear
What is last 100 values? Last 100 ids inserted? Or last 100 rows updated?
Assuming that you are looking for the last 100 roes inserted, you approach has issues. First know that the IDs are not sequentially committed to DB.
For, example ID of a row can be 5 at sometime and ID of a row inserted later can be 4. How this happens is beyond the scope, but just know that it is possible.

Coming to solution 
Just do

```
SELECT TOP 100 * from VALUES ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: The last 100 rows inserted.